# Is it possible to run gitolite on a FreeNAS server?

Tags: storage, truenas, gitolite

We make extensive use of gitolite, both for code management and to host private SparkleShare repositories. I'm looking at building a FreeNAS storage machine, and got to thinking that it runs bsd, has ssh, and therefore should theoretically have all it needs to run gitolite. Has anyone tried this? Is there any reason it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like even if this was possible, it would be to complicated to be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is possible I would not do this. Try have a VM for each service. This will help you later when you will need to migrate or upgrade the services.

Comment: Are you suggesting that gitolite be on a VM somewhere else on the network, and then set up its home directory on nfs or something similar?

Comment: The whole idea is that freeNAS can handle the physical storage, and gitolite would manage revisioning and permissions.

Comment: Depends on the expected load. If flexibility is more important, then gitolite should be a VM. If you need speed may be gitolite should be a stand alone server with a local storage.

Comment: But when you decide what to do take in consideration how you are planning the upgrades for the NAS and for the gitolite.